# How to disable the overscroll in scrollview but only in the top for android?

Tags: android, scrollview, overscroll

I know the we can turn off the overscroll via overscroll mode. But how do i control it in a way the that bottom has the overscroll effect while the top doesn't has the overscroll effect in a scroll view?

Comment: I think you can't, as you can only allow it or disable it at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are one method in `ScrollView` class called `getBottomFadingEdgeStrength()` so you can create a Class that extends `ScrollView` and override the above method.
 like

```
/**
* Created by droidwithme on 23/05/16.
*/
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

public MyScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0.0f;
}
}
```

and return a 0 to this method. 
 this may help you.